# Hyperlink in Login Error message in Maximo 7.5

Tags: maximo

I would like to like to know whether it's possible to add hyperlink to a message that appears in Maximo. For example , if a user is de-activated in Maximo then they get an error message like " You cannot log in at this time. Please contact system Administrator" should appear like **"You cannot log in at this time. Please contact system Administrator or raise request in http://abcd.123.com"** the URL appears as a TEXT instead of hyperlink. Please let me know if anyone has done this before in Maximo 7.5

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly change the value of the the system, NoLogin value via Database Configuration > Select Action > Messages.

Unfortunately, the value will not render as HTML. So, you can put that text in, but something like `<a href="http://abcd.123.com">http://abcd.123.com</a>` will not render as a hyperlink.

You'd have to do some custom editing of the .JSP files to include hyperlinks as part of a specific error message.

[image: system, NoLogin]